# PHP converting String to Integer and knowing when value is not Integer in String format

Tags: php, string, integer, type-conversion

In Java you can try to convert any String value to Integer, but when value is something else, it will throw [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). Is there similar functionality in PHP? I checked [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), but it returns values when String value obviously is not convert-able value.

Comment: php is a loosely typed language, so better get used to it from now :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A language throwing an error is not really a useful feature, it's not what you're actually trying to do.
I assume that you simply want to figure out *if your string is numeric*. For that there's [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) or [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit).

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using `is_numeric()`,then throw an exeption